# Firebase functions - Deploy Completed but doesn't exist in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Follow the guide of using Cloud Functions with Firebase.

1. Setup environment
2. setup project in Firebase
3. Created function
4. command prompt writes that function deployed, but firebase is empty.

I am new with deploying functions so I am sure that it is stupid question and I think I did something wrong in setting up but I checked three times different guides and it looks everything done right. So please if you know what the problem it is can be?

I used this guide and there I done everything till initializing the project
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

After that in index.js I wrote a function

```
        const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(function.config().firebase);

    export.sendNotification = functions.database
                                .ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}')
                                .onWrite(event => {

                                    conts user_id = event.params.user_id;
                                    const notification = event.params.notification_id;

                                    if(!event.data.val()){
                                        return console.log('A notification has been deleted ', notification_id);
                                    }

                                    const payload = {
                                        notification: {
                                            title: "Friend Request",
                                            body: "Received new Friend Request",
                                            icon: "default"
                                        }
                                    };

                                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(/*Token*/, payload).then(response =>{
                                        console.log('');
                                    });
                                });
```

And with the command

```
firebase deploy
```

I tried to deploy function
But in firebase cattegory "Function" it is still empty
[image]

Error in CMD

[image]

Comment: Hey Boris. I have no doubt something went wrong along the way. But it's hard to determine what that is from the information you shared, since we're not sitting next to you looking over our shoulder. Can you share the steps that it takes to reproduce this problem, the exact messages you get along the way, and the results you see. Copy/pasted messages and screenshots are more likely to give the relevant information than your paraphrased description of them. In general: read about [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the chances that we can help you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hello. Thank you for the reply. I just added some more information. (also thank you for firebase in weekend tutorial in Udacity. It was very helpful:)

Comment: Nothing seems wrong in the code. What output does the `firebase deploy` command give?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen than function deployed successful

Comment: Don't paraphrase. Copy the exact text from your console, and add it to your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen now it shows error -- Error occurred while parsing your function triggers -- Unexpected Token... I have read google already - reinstall node.js again go through all steps from guide and now it doesn't work at all

Comment: That's a basic syntax error. At first glance the `/*Token*/` looks like you still need to replace it with the value of the token (as a string).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen have added full error. Thank you for your help

Comment: That's `functions.config` with an `s`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for help. That was not only one mistake after that. It is so unusual write code in note++ after Android Studio and wastes so much time just in looking for a syntax error.lol. I have solved that problem fast and found all syntax errors in couple minutes. So now everything deployed. But anyway yesterday everything was fine but it didn't appear in Firebase. Still, don't know why. Thank you again. See you in Google:)

Answer (score 0):

> There is syntax error, Please change below line in your code

```
admin.initializeApp(function.config().firebase);
```

to

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late here but it might help somebody else. You're right, it is typo. The correct command is:

```
exports
```

not

```
export
```